# Hibernate Query no work

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm trying to update one row in my db using Query but I have no idea why it doesn't work.

I use this method:

```
@Override
    public void updateImage(String avatar, int employeeId) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        try {
            Transaction transaction = null;

            Query query = session.createQuery("UPDATE vt_employee SET emp_avatar=? WHERE id_employee=?");
            query.setString(0, avatar);
            query.setInteger(1, employeeId);

            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            query.executeUpdate();
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.clear();
        }
    }
```

My values avatar and employeeId of course are not null or empty I checked it by display in console. My table in db is vt_employee and fields like emp_avatar and id_employee exist.
I checked in which place is problem and problem is in createQuery, if I tried to display arguments before session.createQuery then they displayed in console but after this one line they don't.

Could someone help to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try this `session.createQuery("UPDATE vt_employee SET emp_avatar=:emp_avatar WHERE id_employee=:id_employee")` and then use `setParameter` like `query.setParameter("emp_avatar",avatar)`  and `query.setParameter("id_employee",employeeId)` ?

Comment: @hadi-j unfortunately it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this.

```
public void updateImage(String avatar, int employeeId) {
    String hql = "UPDATE vt_employee set emp_avatar =:avatar WHERE id_employee =:employeeId";
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("avatar",avatar);
    query.setParameter("employeeId",employeeId);
            int i = query.executeUpdate();
    if (i > 0) {
        System.Out.println("Updated..") ;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error or issue with tht..? can you please tell